# DC-DC converter with 200V output?

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion

First of all, I'm a mechanical (robotics) engineer, so I do not know much about electric power systems.
I'm making a mobile robot that should have electrical motors and drive system.
The problem is that I have a 240V Li-ion Battery System only, and the Driver Input must be under 200V! 
I can set the battery charging limits to 200V  but I want to use the full range of battery power.
So I'm trying to find a DC-DC converter that converts DC input voltage (of 230V) to output of 200V or 195V, with up to 60 A current.

Does anybody know about something like this?

Specifications:

- the peak current   : 60A with 3sec
- continuous current : 20A
- the total power   : 13kW.

Comment: How much power/current do you want to draw from it?

Comment: If everything else fails you can consider a motor-generator set.

Comment: "very grad to you that you've read through this line". I was so curious to know how it would end that I only read the last line :-)

Comment: You might try the Ultravolt line of high power DC DC converters from [PPM Power](http://www.ppmpower.co.uk/high_power_c_series_high_power_density_hv_power_supplies/).

Comment: Are you really constrained to using that battery system? Given that it will be a huge stack of individual cells, could you not remove some to bring it down to 200V? Note also that the actual voltage will vary by 20% depending on state of charge.

Comment: @tmclavis: You should edit the additional specifications into the question itself, rather than leaving them as comments. Also, "13kW" is a power specification, not an energy specification.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, as of now I'll consider about removing some cells on the battery.......

Comment: It's very funny that it turned out to be so much easier and cheaper to reduce the battery voltage than to make a pretty powerful DC/DC converter :) It's a perfect example of the KISS principle. To tell you the truth, many technicians would simply end up using the full 240V as long as nothing burns. It's all those enginners that care so much about maximum specifications.

Comment: modifying the battery pack to match the motor looks like the better choice. check with 'sanyo' for battery requirements. i remember my friend buying a customised battery pack from sanyo for his application.

Answer (score 6):

Building a 12-13 kW power converter so that you can use the battery you have with the motor controller you have is basically a non-starter for various reasons. You already have one suggestion to modify the battery pack to match the motor controller, so let me also suggest that you consider finding a different motor controller that's a better match for the original battery pack.

Answer (score 5):

As you are going to need to learn some more about power electronics to make this overall project succeed I will just give a conceptual outline of one method. IF this proves useful in due course ask more when you know more.

A basic buck converter will do what you want.

Essentially a buck converter can be thought of a s PWMN chopped DC signal followed by an LC filter.  If you ]feed 240V max into a PWM switch and switch the switch with a 200/240 =~ 83% duty cycle square wave, the average output voltage will be 200/240ths of the input. Feed this via an inductor to a capacitor and place a "catch diode from inductor  input to ground such that it does not conduct when 240V is applied. It will carry inductor circulating current when the switch is off.

That's it.
 Building one that works at 60A at 200V is slightly harder.

[Wikipedia - Buck converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter)
 Image below from link above.

[image]

Vout ~~~~= Vin x Ts_on/(Ts_on + Ts_off)

[Idea starters here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=buck+converter+200V+60a&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=7-hyUOjVEe2PiAe6oYGQDg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=2133&bih=1201)

Comment: I think you know this, but the fixed duty cycle formula only works in continuous conduction mode. This means that you either need to have a minimum continuous load requirement (unlikely with a motor driver), or you need to use synchronous rectification (e.g., a MOSFET that allows current to flow in either direction).

Comment: @DaveTweed - Yes - I've spent too many hours playing with buck converters in various modes. Fine detail is/was lacking as he is going to have to get rather more involved in the subject than he is so far for it all to work. At that stage a bit more 'reality' will need to be applied. | If I was in his position I'd be looking hard at trying to either get motor controller Vin up or battery voltage down. 60A at 200V is not trivial and eliminating the need for a voltage transformer would be best of all.